# How to change .then to trycach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, try-catch

I would like to rewrite the following useState function using async and try-catch, I want to know how to do it without the .then/catch.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {getPopularMovies, getUpcomingMovies} from './../services/services';
import {SliderBox} from 'react-native-image-slider-box';

const Home = () => {
    const [movieImages, setMovieImages] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const moviePath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getUpcomingMovies()
            .then(movies => {
                const moviesImagesArr = []
                movies.forEach(movie => {
                    moviesImagesArr.push(`${moviePath}${movie.poster_path}`);
                });
            setMovieImages(moviesImagesArr);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            setError(err);
          });      
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <SliderBox images={movieImages} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

So I would like to rewrite the following piece of code and return the new function inside the useEffect:

```
getUpcomingMovies()
                .then(movies => {
                    const moviesImagesArr = []
                    movies.forEach(movie => {
                        moviesImagesArr.push(`${moviePath}${movie.poster_path}`);
                    });
                setMovieImages(moviesImagesArr);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                setError(err);
              }); 
        
        useEffect(() => {
              new function   
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a code snippet like this:

```js
function test() {
  foo(1, 2).then((result) => {
    console.log("Result:", result);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  });
}
```

... can be rewritten using async/await like this:

```js
async function test() {
  try {
    const result = await foo(1, 2);
    console.log("Result:", result);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  }
}
```

In case of a nested `.then()` call like this:

```js
foo().then((res) => {
  bar(res).then((res2) => {
    console.log(res2);
  });
});
```

... it becomes:

```js
try {
  const res = await foo();
  const res2 = await bar(res);
  console.log(res2);
}
catch (err) {
  // do nothing in this case
}
```

This should help you rewriting the code.